# Can not get DateTime from String in format dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:ms

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am successful in getting `NSDate` from `String` format `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm`
However, when I try `String` in format `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:ms` it doesn't work

Here is my code

```
    NSString *time1 = @"28-04-2016 09:59";
    NSDateFormatter * formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
    NSDate *dateTime1 = [formatter1 dateFromString:time1];

    NSLog(@"time1 = %@",time1);
    NSLog(@"dateTime1 = %@",dateTime1);



    NSString *time2 = @"28-04-2016 09:59:23:5923";
    NSDateFormatter * formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:ms"];
    NSDate *dateTime2 = [formatter2 dateFromString:time2];
    NSLog(@"time2 = %@",time2);
    NSLog(@"dateTime2 = %@",dateTime2);
```

Here is the log

```
2016-04-28 10:24:31.393 EarCrush[2370:43278] time1 = 28-04-2016 09:59
2016-04-28 10:24:31.394 EarCrush[2370:43278] dateTime1 = 2016-04-28 02:59:00 +0000
2016-04-28 10:24:31.394 EarCrush[2370:43278] time2 = 28-04-2016 09:59:23:5923
2016-04-28 10:24:31.395 EarCrush[2370:43278] dateTime2 = (null)
```

**UPDATE**
If I use the format `@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSSS"`
I will got the result:

```
2016-04-28 10:50:56.281 EarCrush[3237:56438] dateTime2 = 2016-04-28 02:59:23 +0000
```

the dateTime2 is not `null` but the millisecond is missing

Any help would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [this](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) list fractional seconds are capital `S`

```
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSSS"];
```

Consider that `NSLog` does not display the fractional seconds.
To do that you need to convert the date back to string with the date formatter.

Comment: Note that (in my testing in an OS X playground in Xcode 7.3.1), `NSDateFormatter` will only parse up to three fractional digits, regardless of how many `S` you use.

Comment: @vadian i'm really sorry about my confusing. i have update my post. please see it again

Comment: you are right. I convert date back to string I now I can see the millisecond. thank you so much

Comment: @robmayoff thank you. now I saw I can only get three fractional digits